# Atom snippet with variable in prefix

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets, prefix

Is it possible to create snippets for atom with variables in the prefix?

For example:

if I type: `getPosts::` and tab, it should create something like this:

```
public static function getPosts(){

}
```

and put my cursor inside the function.

I allready tried

```
'.text.html.php':
  'create public static function':
    'prefix': '$1::'
    'body': 'public static function $1(){\n\t${2://code...}\n}'
```

but this does not work.

Comment: For what, Java? I think there are lots of plugins to do things like this, and some of it is built-in by default (I can think of some HTML examples), but Atom is for any number of languages so for it to generate code scaffolds like that for a particular language you'd probably need to customize it with a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to have variables in an Atom snippet. Please see more here: [Snippet Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538042/snippet-variables/42372763#42372763)