# Snippet Variables?

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets

Is there any way that we can create snippets in Atom with variables (someway like Emmet did in HTML)?

Here's an example that we want to achieve:

From: `p4`

To: `padding: 4% 4% 4% 4%`

( From: `p[i]` to padding: `i% i% i% i%` ) (the user input `p+[i]` , `i` is variable )

Comment: For me it's not really clear, what is the difference from `$1` that you can use in snippet. Please add some more explanation

Comment: It's like: if you press in "p4" , the result will be "padding 4% 4%" .
If you press in "p5" , the result will be "padding 5% 5%" .
Something like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge you are not able to do that with Atom snippets because they are composed with just CSON (i.e. no scripting). So while you can't do that you can use a single variable and expand it into multiple locations in your snippet, something I learned in this blog that I read [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/02/21/turbocharge-coding-snippets/?utm_source=stackoverflow-ao&utm_campaign=turbocharge-coding-snippets&utm_medium=referral)

Taken from that post, here is example CSON to do that:

```
'.source.css':
   'Padding With Mostly Identical Values':
     'prefix': 'pwmiv'
     'body': 'padding: ${1:num}px ${1:num}$2px ${1:num}$3px ${1:num}$4px;'
```

Looking at it, it looks like you can also tab through each placeholder to edit any paddings that need to be different.